# How to filter books, so you get the authors books and not every book available, when you use ListView and DetailView (Django)

Tags: django, listview, filter, one-to-many, detailview

Authors books should only be displayed when tapping the authors name in the ListView.

***models.py***

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.text import slugify

class Author(models.Model):´
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=False, null=False)


class Book(models.Model):

    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
```

---

***views.py***

```
from app.models import Book, Author
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Author
    ordering = ['-id']
    template_name = 'app/home.html'


class AuthorView(DetailView):
    model = Author
    template_name = 'app/author.html'
    

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # author_pk = self.kwargs.get('pk', None)

        # Tried this logic, but it makes no sense after I looked at it more close
        books = Book.objects.all()
        if books.author is Author.pk:
            books_filtered = books.objects.all()

        

        context = super(AuthorView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

        context['books'] = books_filtered
        return context
```

---

Now when all authors are displayed on the home page with `ListView`, when someone clicks on an author they should see only the books the author has made with the `DetailView`

This [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context) I tried but it will only display all the books

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `self.object` to filter the books:

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    books = Book.objects.filter(author=self.object)
    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass this to the template. In the template, you can work with:

```
{% for book in object.book_set.all %}
    {{book.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

here `object` is the `Author` for which we retrieve the books.